# How to properly request a transfer to another country when I already have a work visa?

Tags: job-search, human-resources, visa, internal-transfer

I work in a multi-national IT service company. I have recently acquired a permanent resident visa for Canada. I have six months to land in Canada. I am really happy with my company and would love to continue working with it in Canada as it has offices there.

Now here is my situation:
I asked my own supervisor for guidance to find a project in this regard, but she seems reluctant to help me.

A friend of mine who works in HR, told me that there are multiple openings in Canada. He got me in touch with one of the HRs in Canada. I have given him my profile details and resume, but he doesn't seem to be interested. When I dropped him a follow-up e-mail after a fortnight, he responded saying he had accidentally deleted the resume and asked me to re-send.

I am trying to connect with my own HR manager, but he always responds with "I am busy", "In a meeting" etc.

I get the vibe that eventhough there are multiple openings in my domain, the people from HR are just not interested!

If  nothing works out I would have to submit my resignation as my company has a three month notice period and I don't want my visa to expire.

What should be the course of action so that I can get a proper response and find a position in another country in my company?

Comment: Did you say "I would like to transfer to Canada" or did you say "I am moving to Canada, I would like keep working at this company" (assuming the move is set in stone)? They're very different - the one is a choice between keeping you where you are versus moving you, and the other is a choice between moving you versus losing you. Did you tell them you already have a visa?

Comment: Who are you intending to pay for the relocation costs?  You or your company?

Comment: Does your company have these position posted on internal/external job site? You might have to officially apply to the other position

Comment: @Dukeling I told them I am moving to Canada and would like to continue working with the company. I have also given them my VISA details along with my resume.

Comment: @SnarkShark It doesnt matter. That is not a deal breaker for me. In my company the policy is that they pay for travel and first month rent. But I am willing to bear those costs(although I have not indicated this to them)

Comment: @curt1893 They do have an internal job posting site. But my job level is restricted from viewing postings in another country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the vibe that eventhough there are multiple openings in my
>   domain, the people from HR are just not interested!
>
> If nothing works out I would have to submit my resignation as my
>   company has a three month notice period and I don't want my visa to
>   expire.
>
> What should be the course of action so that I can get a proper
>   response and find a position in another country in my company?

You took the proper actions - contacting HR in both locales. Keep being persistent with your local HR rep. Keep trying to schedule a face-to-face meeting to discuss the possibilities.

And if you are on good terms with your immediate boss, you might try enlisting their help again. You might have to put your cards on the table and tell them that you will have to leave the company if you cannot transfer.

Since the only alternative is leaving the company, a good boss who believes you have worked hard and are a valuable asset to the company will help point you in the right direction.

Hopefully your performance to date in the company show them that you are an employee who would be valuable in Canada.

> He got me in touch with one of the HRs in Canada. I have given him my
>   profile details and resume, but he doesn't seem to be interested.

Unfortunately, this could be laziness on their part, or you may simply not fit the requirements of a position in Canada at this time.

You will need to be prepared to hand in your notice if time starts to run out.

Comment: Thanks Joe! Coming to your earlier comment of why I think my supervisor is reluctant; Any time I bring up or try to bring up a discussion of my future my supervisor just ends it with a line like "I'm not sure" , "I don't know" etc. or changes the topic.
On a side note, I did contact my team lead - He has asked me to get in touch with the unit delivery head(our company has verticals called units like retail,finance, manufacturing based on the clientele) as he would be the one conducting my exit interview. He told me he should be able to get in touch with some contacts. Will update soon...